# Apache is executing 404 urls twice

Tags: apache, debugging, ssl

While trying to debug slow apache response times (apparently due to rules in `.htaccess`) I found a different issue.

Apache seems to execute `404` urls twice.

Here are the `ssl_request_logs`. The first number in the logs is the time in (microseconds), it goes down significantly when I disable `.htaccess` but thats another discussion.

```
253125 [18/Dec/2022:12:19:18 +0000] 1.1.1.1 www.example.com "GET /testing404 HTTP/1.1" 1018 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 404
202625 [18/Dec/2022:12:19:18 +0000] 1.1.1.1 www.example.com "GET /testing404 HTTP/1.1" 1018 "Mozilla/5.0,(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7),AppleWebKit/537.36,(KHTML, like Gecko),Chrome/108.0.0.0,Safari/537.36" 404
```

While `200` (and `301`'s) show up just once

```
358050 [18/Dec/2022:12:22:00 +0000] 1.1.1.1 www.example.com "GET /account-login HTTP/1.1" 13844 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 200
```

The below are the `ssl_error_logs` when trying a `404` and using the debug log level. I tried `trace8` but not sure all the extra data can help diagnose. I also renamed the `.htaccess` so its disabled and wont fill the log with even more unnecessary data. (removed text like `pid` info, times, IP's to get under character limit)

```
[Sun Dec 18 516095 ] [ssl:info]   AH01964: Connection to child 64 established (server www.example.com:443)
[Sun Dec 18 516302 ]  ssl_engine_rand.c(126): Server: Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Sun Dec 18 516581 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2206):  OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Sun Dec 18 516668 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: before SSL initialization
[Sun Dec 18 516739 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a8400d433] 
[Sun Dec 18 516768 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 314/314 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a8400d438] 
[Sun Dec 18 516783 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: before SSL initialization
[Sun Dec 18 516839 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2397):  AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername www.example.com found
[Sun Dec 18 516996 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
[Sun Dec 18 517291 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
[Sun Dec 18 517383 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
[Sun Dec 18 517427 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
[Sun Dec 18 517696 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: write 4096/4096 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 517746 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
[Sun Dec 18 520249 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
[Sun Dec 18 520305 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: write 494/494 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 520399 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write finished
[Sun Dec 18 520415 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Sun Dec 18 619351 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019853] 
[Sun Dec 18 619448 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 1/1 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019858] 
[Sun Dec 18 619461 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019853] 
[Sun Dec 18 619470 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 69/69 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019858] 
[Sun Dec 18 619543 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Sun Dec 18 619667 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read finished
[Sun Dec 18 619698 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2210):  OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Sun Dec 18 619733 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2259):  AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.3, Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Sun Dec 18 619841 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(510): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x01 -> subcache 1)
[Sun Dec 18 619879 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(864): AH00847: insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32)
[Sun Dec 18 619888 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(869): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/209
[Sun Dec 18 619898 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(531): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Sun Dec 18 619911 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2066): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=0140749c6670cdfacb34513b315d9251af355e0b6829622ef21ca6bef4d8c69b timeout=300s (session caching)
[Sun Dec 18 619939 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: write 79/79 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 620002 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Sun Dec 18 620047 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(510): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x97 -> subcache 23)
[Sun Dec 18 620070 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(864): AH00847: insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32)
[Sun Dec 18 620078 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(869): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/209
[Sun Dec 18 620107 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(531): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Sun Dec 18 620116 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2066): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=9765b1a6423b5ddaca014e359ecad943fba6da0efc0700fc68ca6cefa7dd3431 timeout=300s (session caching)
[Sun Dec 18 620134 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: write 79/79 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 620172 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215):  OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Sun Dec 18 61 ] [http2:trace1]  h2_c1.c(218):  h2_h2, process_conn
[Sun Dec 18 620247 ] [http2:trace1]  h2_c1.c(226):  h2_h2, process_conn, new connection using protocol 'http/1.1', direct=0, tls acceptable=1
[Sun Dec 18 620256 ] [http2:trace1]  h2_c1.c(282):  h2_h2, declined
[Sun Dec 18 620311 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84007ea3] 
[Sun Dec 18 620334 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: read 1265/1265 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84007ea8] 
[Sun Dec 18 620363 ] [core:trace5]  protocol.c(713):  Request received from client: GET /testing404page HTTP/1.1
[Sun Dec 18 620528 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(422):  AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 64 (server www.example.com:443)
[Sun Dec 18 620560 ]  http_request.c(436):  Headers received from client:
[Sun Dec 18 620569 ]    Host: www.example.com
[Sun Dec 18 620576 ]    Connection: close
[Sun Dec 18 620584 ]    Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, */*; q=0.8, application/signed-exchange; v=b3; q=0.9
[Sun Dec 18 620592 ]    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
[Sun Dec 18 620599 ]    Accept-Encoding: identity
[Sun Dec 18 620605 ]    Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.9
[Sun Dec 18 620612 ]    Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.929352060.1671367811; _ga_LN3Q7T4VE2=GS1.1.1671367811.1.0.1671367815.0.0.0
[Sun Dec 18 620620 ]    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
[Sun Dec 18 620627 ]    CDN-ServerId: 1027
[Sun Dec 18 620633 ]    CDN-ServerZone: ISR
[Sun Dec 18 620648 ]    CDN-Host: www.example.com
[Sun Dec 18 620655 ]    CDN-ConnectionId: 626360907
[Sun Dec 18 620662 ]    CDN-MobileDevice: false
[Sun Dec 18 620669 ]    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
[Sun Dec 18 620676 ]    BunnyCDN-LBKey: j0YiR5gUfYiZmQrWSLV6opVewPUZFwJD21K1W9dkKWg4EnYSjbS5c9
[Sun Dec 18 620683 ]    sec-ch-ua: \\"Not?A_Brand\\";v=\\"8\\", \\"Chromium\\";v=\\"108\\", \\"Google Chrome\\";v=\\"108\\"
[Sun Dec 18 620691 ]    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
[Sun Dec 18 620698 ]    sec-ch-ua-platform: \\"macOS\\"
[Sun Dec 18 620705 ]    sec-fetch-site: none
[Sun Dec 18 620712 ]    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
[Sun Dec 18 620718 ]    sec-fetch-user: ?1
[Sun Dec 18 620725 ]    sec-fetch-dest: document
[Sun Dec 18 620732 ]    CDN-RequestCountryCode: IL
[Sun Dec 18 620738 ]    CDN-RequestId: 2ec409327996c82006a7bd1489fd2b69
[Sun Dec 18 620745 ]    CDN-LoopCount: 1
[Sun Dec 18 620752 ]    CDN-ProxyVer: 1.03
[Sun Dec 18 620759 ]    Via: BunnyCDN
[Sun Dec 18 620765 ]    X-Real-IP: 80.178.138.38
[Sun Dec 18 620772 ]    X-Forwarded-For: 80.178.138.38
[Sun Dec 18 620779 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginPathBase64: L3Rlc3Rpbmc0MDRwYWdl
[Sun Dec 18 620786 ]    CDN-RequestUrl: 
[Sun Dec 18 621203 ] [authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(818):  AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Dec 18 621226 ] [authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(818):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Dec 18 621235 ] [core:trace3]  request.c(362):  request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /testing404page
[Sun Dec 18 627213 ] [core:info]   AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/testing404page
[Sun Dec 18 627305 ] [http:trace3]  http_filters.c(1132):  Response sent with status 404, headers:
[Sun Dec 18 627317 ] [http:trace5]  http_filters.c(1139):    Date: Sun, 18 Dec  12:50:51 GMT
[Sun Dec 18 627325 ] [http:trace5]  http_filters.c(1142):    Server: Apache/2.4.54 (codeit) OpenSSL/1.1.1q+quic
[Sun Dec 18 627334 ]  http_filters.c(961):    Content-Length: 196
[Sun Dec 18 627341 ]  http_filters.c(961):    Connection: close
[Sun Dec 18 627348 ]  http_filters.c(961):    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[Sun Dec 18 627371 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(1856):  coalesce: have 0 bytes, adding 200 more (buckets=1)
[Sun Dec 18 627812 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(1856):  coalesce: have 200 bytes, adding 196 more (buckets=1)
[Sun Dec 18 627837 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(1917):  coalesce: passing on 396 bytes
[Sun Dec 18 627882 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: write 418/418 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a84219233] 
[Sun Dec 18 628017 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406):  OpenSSL: write 24/24 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a84219233] 
[Sun Dec 18 628048 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2225):  OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Sun Dec 18 628060 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_io.c(1151):  AH02001: Connection closed to child 64 with standard shutdown (server www.example.com:443)
[Sun Dec 18 638828 ] [ssl:info]  AH01964: Connection to child 128 established (server www.example.com:443)
[Sun Dec 18 639010 ]  ssl_engine_rand.c(126): Server: Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Sun Dec 18 639234 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2206): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Sun Dec 18 639331 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: before SSL initialization
[Sun Dec 18 639396 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a8400d433] 
[Sun Dec 18 639432 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 308/308 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a8400d438] 
[Sun Dec 18 639449 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: before SSL initialization
[Sun Dec 18 639502 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2397): AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername www.example.com found
[Sun Dec 18 639689 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
[Sun Dec 18 639990 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
[Sun Dec 18 640102 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
[Sun Dec 18 640141 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
[Sun Dec 18 640454 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: write 4096/4096 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 640534 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
[Sun Dec 18 643242 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
[Sun Dec 18 643321 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: write 478/478 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 643421 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write finished
[Sun Dec 18 643446 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Sun Dec 18 747121 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019853] 
[Sun Dec 18 747211 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 1/1 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019858] 
[Sun Dec 18 747231 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019853] 
[Sun Dec 18 747241 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 53/53 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84019858] 
[Sun Dec 18 747274 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: TLSv1.3 early data
[Sun Dec 18 747353 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS read finished
[Sun Dec 18 747376 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2210): OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Sun Dec 18 747411 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2259): AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.3, Cipher: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Sun Dec 18 747607 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(510): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x4d -> subcache 13)
[Sun Dec 18 747665 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(864): AH00847: insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32)
[Sun Dec 18 747683 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(869): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/194
[Sun Dec 18 747697 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(531): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Sun Dec 18 747710 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2066): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=4d936df371aa4cf9fcdf61d23982017034ab7cec351ec23dd1da80ed6e672f2a timeout=300s (session caching)
[Sun Dec 18 747764 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: write 79/79 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 747826 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Sun Dec 18 747889 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(510): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store (0x66 -> subcache 6)
[Sun Dec 18 747941 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(864): AH00847: insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32)
[Sun Dec 18 747959 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(869): AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/194
[Sun Dec 18 747983 ] [socache_shmcb:debug]  mod_socache_shmcb.c(531): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully
[Sun Dec 18 748002 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2066): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=SET status=OK id=661ae4bb6e6fe52f898a8956c4644e3fe30126ec61ce49825836bdd963c61f2b timeout=300s (session caching)
[Sun Dec 18 748040 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: write 79/79 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a840166f0] 
[Sun Dec 18 748106 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2215): OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
[Sun Dec 18 748159 ] [http2:trace1]  h2_c1.c(218): h2_h2, process_conn
[Sun Dec 18 748195 ] [http2:trace1]  h2_c1.c(226): h2_h2, process_conn, new connection using protocol 'http/1.1', direct=0, tls acceptable=1
[Sun Dec 18 748205 ] [http2:trace1]  h2_c1.c(282): h2_h2, declined
[Sun Dec 18 748270 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84007ea3] 
[Sun Dec 18 748293 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: read 1791/1791 bytes from BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84007ea8] 
[Sun Dec 18 748331 ] [core:trace5]  protocol.c(713): Request received from client: GET /testing404page HTTP/1.1
[Sun Dec 18 748543 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(422): AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 128 (server www.example.com:443)
[Sun Dec 18 748576 ]  http_request.c(436): Headers received from client:
[Sun Dec 18 748585 ]    CDN-GzipEnabled: true
[Sun Dec 18 748592 ]    CDN-BrotliEnabled: true
[Sun Dec 18 748600 ]    CDN-RequestUrl: https://www.example.com/testing404page
[Sun Dec 18 748607 ]    CDN-CacheKey: luakey_eb91c56d-6_149_/testing404page
[Sun Dec 18 748614 ]    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*; q=0.8,application/signed-exchange; v=b3; q=0.9
[Sun Dec 18 748628 ]    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0,(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7),AppleWebKit/537.36,(KHTML, like Gecko),Chrome/108.0.0.0,Safari/537.36
[Sun Dec 18 748636 ]    Accept-Language: en-US,en; q=0.9
[Sun Dec 18 748643 ]    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
[Sun Dec 18 748650 ]    CDN-ServerId: 1027
[Sun Dec 18 748657 ]    CDN-ServerZone: ISR
[Sun Dec 18 748664 ]    CDN-Host: www.example.com
[Sun Dec 18 748671 ]    CDN-ConnectionId: 626360907
[Sun Dec 18 748677 ]    CDN-MobileDevice: false
[Sun Dec 18 748684 ]    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
[Sun Dec 18 748691 ]    BunnyCDN-LBKey: j0YiR5gUfYiZmQrWSLV6opVewPUZFwJD21K1W9dkKWg4EnYSjbS5c9
[Sun Dec 18 748698 ]    sec-ch-ua: \\"Not?A_Brand\\";v=\\"8\\", \\"Chromium\\";v=\\"108\\", \\"Google Chrome\\";v=\\"108\\"
[Sun Dec 18 748706 ]    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
[Sun Dec 18 748713 ]    sec-ch-ua-platform: \\"macOS\\"
[Sun Dec 18 748720 ]    sec-fetch-site: none
[Sun Dec 18 748726 ]    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
[Sun Dec 18 748733 ]    sec-fetch-user: ?1
[Sun Dec 18 748740 ]    sec-fetch-dest: document
[Sun Dec 18 748746 ]    CDN-RequestCountryCode: IL
[Sun Dec 18 748754 ]    CDN-RequestId: 2ec409327996c82006a7bd1489fd2b69
[Sun Dec 18 748761 ]    CDN-LoopCount: 1
[Sun Dec 18 748767 ]    CDN-ProxyVer: 1.03
[Sun Dec 18 748774 ]    Via: BunnyCDN
[Sun Dec 18 748781 ]    X-Real-IP: 80.178.138.38
[Sun Dec 18 748788 ]    X-Forwarded-For: 80.178.138.38
[Sun Dec 18 748799 ]    BunnyCDN-SentToOptimizer: false
[Sun Dec 18 748806 ]    BunnyCDN-StorageToken: 2YQhY50fYNCjlYTHZY0MqQepFPIuYmptHWQZKqwE
[Sun Dec 18 748814 ]    BunnyCDN-CachePath: __bcdn_perma_cache__/pullzone__eb91c56d-6__149/___testing404page___/
[Sun Dec 18 748820 ]    BunnyCDN-CacheKey: ___file___
[Sun Dec 18 748827 ]    BunnyCDN-StorageZone: tedty
[Sun Dec 18 748834 ]    BunnyCDN-PermaCache: true
[Sun Dec 18 748841 ]    BunnyCDN-RequestUri: L3Rlc3Rpbmc0MDRwYWdl
[Sun Dec 18 748847 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginPort: 443
[Sun Dec 18 748854 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginScheme: https
[Sun Dec 18 748861 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginPath: %2Ftesting404page
[Sun Dec 18 748868 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginPathBase64: L3Rlc3Rpbmc0MDRwYWdl
[Sun Dec 18 748875 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginHostHeader: www.example.com
[Sun Dec 18 748881 ]    BunnyCDN-OriginHost: 192.237.172.37
[Sun Dec 18 748888 ]    Host: www.example.com
[Sun Dec 18 748895 ]    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
[Sun Dec 18 749107 ] [authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(818): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Dec 18 749130 ] [authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(818): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Dec 18 749139 ] [core:trace3]  request.c(362): request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /testing404page
[Sun Dec 18 755757 ] [core:info]  AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/testing404page
[Sun Dec 18 755853 ] [http:trace3]  http_filters.c(1132): Response sent with status 404, headers:
[Sun Dec 18 755874 ] [http:trace5]  http_filters.c(1139):   Date: Sun, 18 Dec  12:50:51 GMT
[Sun Dec 18 755883 ] [http:trace5]  http_filters.c(1142):   Server: Apache/2.4.54 (codeit) OpenSSL/1.1.1q+quic
[Sun Dec 18 755891 ]  http_filters.c(961):   Content-Length: 196
[Sun Dec 18 755909 ]  http_filters.c(961):   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
[Sun Dec 18 755931 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(1856): coalesce: have 0 bytes, adding 181 more (buckets=1)
[Sun Dec 18 755950 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(1856): coalesce: have 181 bytes, adding 196 more (buckets=1)
[Sun Dec 18 755959 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(1917): coalesce: passing on 377 bytes
[Sun Dec 18 756002 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: write 399/399 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a84217463] 
[Sun Dec 18 756050 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2415): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84217463]
[Sun Dec 18 12:50:56.761328 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2415): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f7a84007b70 [mem: 7f7a84217463]
[Sun Dec 18 12:50:56.761470 ]  ssl_engine_io.c(2406): OpenSSL: write 24/24 bytes to BIO#7f7a84004aa0 [mem: 7f7a84217463] 
[Sun Dec 18 12:50:56.761586 ]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(2225): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Sun Dec 18 12:50:56.761613 ] [ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_io.c(1151): AH02001: Connection closed to child 128 with standard shutdown (server www.example.com:443)
```

If it helps here are the enabled modules.

```
Loaded Modules:
      core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module 
 actions_module 
 alias_module 
 allowmethods_module 
 auth_basic_module 
 auth_digest_module 
 authn_anon_module 
 authn_core_module 
 authn_dbd_module 
 authn_dbm_module 
 authn_file_module 
 authn_socache_module 
 authz_core_module 
 authz_dbd_module 
 authz_dbm_module 
 authz_groupfile_module 
 authz_host_module 
 authz_owner_module 
 authz_user_module 
 autoindex_module 
 brotli_module 
 cache_module 
 cache_disk_module 
 cache_socache_module 
 data_module 
 dbd_module 
 deflate_module 
 dir_module 
 dumpio_module 
 echo_module 
 env_module 
 expires_module 
 ext_filter_module 
 filter_module 
 headers_module 
 include_module 
 info_module 
 log_config_module 
 logio_module 
 macro_module 
 mime_magic_module 
 mime_module 
 negotiation_module 
 remoteip_module 
 reqtimeout_module 
 request_module 
 rewrite_module 
 setenvif_module 
 slotmem_plain_module 
 slotmem_shm_module 
 socache_dbm_module 
 socache_memcache_module 
 socache_redis_module 
 socache_shmcb_module 
 status_module 
 substitute_module 
 suexec_module 
 unique_id_module 
 unixd_module 
 userdir_module 
 version_module 
 vhost_alias_module 
 watchdog_module 
 dav_module 
 dav_fs_module 
 dav_lock_module 
 lua_module 
 mpm_worker_module 
 proxy_module 
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module 
 lbmethod_byrequests_module 
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module 
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module 
 proxy_ajp_module 
 proxy_balancer_module 
 proxy_connect_module 
 proxy_express_module 
 proxy_fcgi_module 
 proxy_fdpass_module 
 proxy_ftp_module 
 proxy_http_module 
 proxy_hcheck_module 
 proxy_scgi_module 
 proxy_uwsgi_module 
 proxy_wstunnel_module 
 ssl_module 
 systemd_module 
 cgid_module 
 http2_module 
 php5_module 
 proxy_http2_module 
 pagespeed_module
```

It's a dedicated server/IP and only one domain.

I've played around with the `<VirtualHost>`'s to see if thats the issue but nothing worked.

Here is my `httpd.conf` (cleaned up for the post)

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"


Listen 80




Include conf.modules.d/*.conf


User apache
Group apache




<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"


<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted


 </Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks


    AllowOverride All

   
    Require all granted
</Directory>



<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>




ErrorLog "logs/error_log"



LogLevel error



    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
     LogFormat "%D %h %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

<IfModule log_config_module>
  
    #LogFormat "%D %h %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    #LogFormat "%D %h %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %b" common


  
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
   
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types


    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz


   
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>


AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
   
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>




EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

And the `ssl.conf` (also cleaned up)

```
Listen 443 https


SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog


SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300


SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512



SSLCryptoDevice builtin
#SSLCryptoDevice ubsec





<VirtualHost *:443>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"




<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  LogLevel debug trace5
</IfModule>



SSLEngine on


SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3


SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA






<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>


BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]"nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%D %t %{X-Forwarded-For}i %{Host}i \"%r\" %b \"%{User-Agent}i\" %>s"


ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Could this madness be normal and I'm missing the logic behind it?

Perhaps there is a better way to debug and find the issue?

Any insight or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

**Edit 1**

Here is the `php.conf` - I had it renamed (disabled) during the above tests but it seems I need it enabled for my admin panel. Probably doesn't make a difference but thought to post anyway.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php




php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
```

**Edit 2**

This is <s>confirmed</s> not the CDN but I did find another clue. The duplicate entries for 404 pages in apache only show up when you access with the domain. If I access the URL with the IP , just 1 request on apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact the CDN. They make 2 requests when they first encounter a URL. This is due to the way their CDN and push style cache is setup. I'll have to cut down on all the apache re-write rules to lower the server response times.